# Data comes back from API fine but specific fields still undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Im calling an API where Ive made a simple model that mirrors my angular interface completely.

The problem is that even though I define the variable I push the data into of that interface type, it still returns the object fields as undefined. I have no idea why but if anyone knows what simple mistake I might be blindly making please point it out.

The method in my service calling the api

```
    var projectsArray: Array<IDevProject> = [];
    var project : IDevProject;
    return this.http.get<IDevProject[]>(this.baseUrl + 'projects').pipe
    (
      map(data => {
        console.log(data);
        for (const id in data)
        {
          if (data.hasOwnProperty(id))
          {
            console.log("Checking Name >>>> " + data[id].Name);
            projectsArray.push(data[id]);
            project = data[id]; // checked with single objects, they also return properties as undefined
            
          }
        }
        return projectsArray;
      })
    );
```

The call to my service from within ngInit (Parameter passed through is irrelevant)

```
projectsArray: Array<IDevProject> = [];

this.devService.getAllProjects(this.cardType).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.projectsArray = data;
        // console.log(data)
        // console.log(this.projectsArray.length);
        this.getArrayCount();
        // console.log(this.manyProjects)
        this.setMinSixDisplayArray();
      }   
    );
```

And finally the interface used to bind the variable to

```
export interface IDevProject 
{
    Id: number;
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
    Image: string;
}
```

Added image of the console for ref
[image: Added image of the console for ref]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Pascal case for the interface and also trying to access the properties.
You should use camelCase because I can see in the console that you the API response with camelCase.

```
console.log("Checking Name >>>> " + data[id].name);
```

Also, you can consider using prettier to format your code in Angular

Answer (score 0):

The name of properties in your interface should be in lowercase.